# Get HTML tag name from React element?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to get an HTML tag name from a React element (return from a component)? For example:

```
function Foo() {
    return <span>Hello</span>;
}
```

The HTML tag name would be `span`. I know you can look into the `type` property of the React element, but it gets really difficult between SFC and normal components, and even harder when the component depth is rather large. For example:

```
function Bar() {
    return <Foo />;
}
```

Should still return `span`.

Comment: So, why do you even need it?

Comment: @zerkms I have this tree parsing layer in which I need to HTML tag name to properly parse it according to the spec.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

React Elements are a virtual construct, and they don't directly represent DOM elements. There are two types of React Elements - "regular" HTML DOM elements, and instantiations of a React Class. The first one has a "type" because it is extremely simple, stateless, and immutable, and is created only to render its corresponding DOM element (but don't confuse it with the DOM element itself!) An example of this would be `<div>Foo</div>` in JSX or `React.createElement("div", null, "Foo")` in JS.

However instantiations of a React Class don't have a "type" because they don't represent a typical DOM element. When we instantiate a React Class we call it a "Component" to identify it as a single instance of the Class, having a `render` method, encapsulated state, etc. It's impossible to retrieve the "type" of a Component because the actual DOM elements that it will render are completely dependent on its internal state and what the `render` method decides to return. An example of this would be a React Class defined somewhere and then instantiated with `<Foo />` or `React.createElement(Foo)`.

The only way to know what DOM elements a Component is actually rendering is to, well, mount and render it and see what it does. There is no "type" inherent to the component itself. You could conceivably mount a Component, use `ref` to capture the DOM element as it's rendered, and then use a callback function to pass this information back to parent(s).

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div ref={function(el){this.props.whatElementAmI(el)}.bind(this)} >Oh My!</div>
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  whatElementAmI: function(el) {
    console.log(el.nodeName); // "DIV"
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div><Child whatElementAmI={this.whatElementAmI.bind(this)} /></div>
  }
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements

Comment: Thanks for the extensive write up. This is pretty much the conclusion I made while digging around, was just curious if I missed something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

const Span = () => <span>hello</span>
renderToString(<Span />)
// "<span>hello</span>"
```

then use regex to get tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React's [Top-Level API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html) to grab the DOM node. Two caveats: 1) this doesn't work on stateless functional components as you can't put refs on them, and 2) it only works if the component outputs a native DOM element, so it won't work in your second case where the component outputs another React component.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span>Hello</span>;
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._component);
    console.log(domNode.tagName); // "DIV"
  }
  render() {
    return <MyComponent ref={(c) => this._component = c} />
  }
}
```