# (S)CSS React element selector

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm looking for a simple way to select an existing react element in my css. I've tried searching it but only found confusing answers about tons of libraries I can use, and none seemed to fit what I'm trying to do.

I want to have a regular `.scss` file, where if I have the react element called `Foo`, I can do something like this:

```
Foo {
    color: red;
}
```

This would be great because I could continue with `.scss` files which I like, and could select components. How can I do this (or achieve similar behaviour)?

*Notice that I'm not the one creating the element so I can't just apply a class to all of them.*

Comment: No way. Names of React components exists only in JS. They are not presented in HTML in any way (only in not processed JSX), so you can't use CSS to style 'anything'

Comment: @Anarion there could be preprocessors or tools that are used for this. That's what I'm looking for

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121680/get-html-tag-name-from-react-element

Comment: I always call react element by className and style it in Sass,
check my answer in the following

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily, by adding className=Foo and called it in Sass by(.Foo) and by using compiler program to convert Sass to CSS such as (Prepros) and call the CSS file as a link to your main HTML file

Comment: "Notice that I'm not the one creating the element so I can't just apply a class to all of them."
Did you read the question?

Comment: I really don't understand your question clear! but anyway if you want to search about react element properties you can check it by inspect element after adding this tool 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog